# How to limit query after with() method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

i have 2 models. PostModel and CategoriesModel.

```
class PostModel extends Model
{
    protected $table='posts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $guarded=['id'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CategoriesModel::class);
    }
}

class CategoriesModelextends Model
{
    protected $table='categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $guarded=['id'];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PostModel::class);
    }
}
```

I want to get 6 categories with  10 posts.
I used this code in my controller

```
$categories = CategoriesModel::with(['pages' => function($query) {
        $query->limit('10');
    }])->take("6")->get();
```

but this code is wrong. it applies to all records. But the truth is that this query applies per one categories. please help me.thanks

Comment: i think this package will help you    https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Answer (score 4):

there is a laravel package specialized in this called [Eloquent Eager Limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit):

after installing it:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"
```

you should use it inside the models that would apply limited eager loading:

```
class PostModel extends Model
{
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
 // ........
}

class CategoriesModel
extends Model
{

use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
 // ........
}
```

now this query will get the result you want:

```
$categories = CategoriesModel::with(['pages' => function($query) {
        $query->limit('10');
    }])->take("6")->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

For **eager loading** you can do like this with **map** operation :

```
$categories = CategoriesModel::with('pages')->take(6)->get()
  ->map(function($q)
    { $q->pages = $q->pages->take(10); // take only 10 query
      return $q; 
    }
);
```

The reason the above approach is necessary is because the constrained eager loading query roughly translates to SQL like:

Query to select Categories:

```
select * from `categories`
limit 6;
```

Query to fetch relation

```
select * from `categories`
inner join `posts` on `categories`.`id` = `posts`.`category_id`
where `posts`.`category_id` in (id's from categories query)
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your relation name is wrong in your controller. Update your category model by the following code:

```
public function ten_posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany(PostModel::class)->take(10);
}
```

then update your controller with the following code:

```
$categories = CategoriesModel::with('ten_posts')->take(6)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this -

```
$categories = CategoriesModel::with(['pages' => function($query) {
        $query->take('10');
    }])->take("6")->get();
```